# Creating a list of the different numbers that occur in a 2D array using the GPU

Tags: list, cuda, numbers, gpgpu, multidimensional-array

Given a 2D array of integers, for example

3 3 1 1 1

3 3 3 1 1

3 3 3 3 1

3 3 3 2 2

3 3 7 2 2

is there an efficient GPU algorithm, that produces a list of all occuring numbers? 
For example

1 2 3 7

for the 2d array above.

The list does not need to be sorted (so 3 2 1 7 for example would be okay as well).

Comment: GPUs are more suited for problems that involve a lot of computation per thread, so this is unlikely to show a huge speedup by computing it on a GPU. That said, you might be looking at a simpler version of a histogram problem.

Comment: Questions like this make me think about [thrust](http://thrust.github.com/).  You might take a look at the thrust [histogram example](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/source/browse/examples/histogram.cu) for some ideas.  I think you could do this with a [thrust::sort](http://thrust.github.com/doc/group__sorting.html#ga8fd4df95e8e16c89ff92737947daa1f9) followed by [thrust::unique](http://thrust.github.com/doc/group__stream__compaction.html#ga330c12555aa9d382254c9f1296e3edcc), but how fast it would be I'm not sure.

Comment: Need a bit more details: what is the expected size of your array? what is the range of the values?

Comment: the possible integer values range from 1 to about 120000. The size of the output array is about 120000 as well (in the worst case), but expected to be far less, maybe about 20000.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there isn't too large of a range of integers to be dealt with (and that these are non-negative integers) you can make a new array that has the length of the range of possible integers in your original array with values initialized to zero.

Then, when a thread finds a number it increments that index of the array by one (so if we see the integer 4 we do something like `result[4]++`. We won't need to sync here since all we'll care about is whether or not a given index of this result array has a value of zero or not.

Of course this can be done if we'll expect negative integers as well - we'll just need twice the space in our result array.

Comment: Remember that the big performance bottleneck here will be your memory. (this will be painfully slow if you do not take it into account). This is because the access on your output counter will be made in a non-coalesced order. A better algorithm would make use of the shared memory to compute smaller versions of the histogram per block, and synchronize all of the blocks at the end.

Comment: It seems to me the request also includes a desire to collapse the list down to just the values that are present (a "sparse" histogram).

Comment: The output counter can be in shared memory until you actually finish all the computation. But this assumes relatively low range on the values